# alert sound when start recording

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

First time i am capturing video in my App, but when i start capturing i want that button click sound as native application. I have searched a lot and came to know that it is a system sound. Can anyone please tell me how can i add that sound in my application when i start capturing video and when i stop capturing.

Currently i am using AVAudioPlayer to play sound as shown below

```
  NSURL *url1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:str withExtension:@"wav"];
_startAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:nil];
_startAudioPlayer.delegate= self;
[_startAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_startAudioPlayer play];
```

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to start capturing video at that time call this bellow method like this...

```
[self playSound];
```

use my this bellow method for play sound...

```
-(void)playSound
{ 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"adriantnt_release_click" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

first store any mp3 or any audio file in your project folder For Ex: i add `adriantnt_release_click.mp3` file.

Also add `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` in your `.h` file and add `AudioToolbox.framework` in your project..

Comment: @khushbuPatel you try it?? its easy to use and working with any audio file which supported by AVAudioPlayer ... just use my above method.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just import `AudioToolbox.framework`.
Create the URL for the source audio file

```
NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"tap"
                                                withExtension: @"aif"];


// Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance
self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];

// Create a system sound object representing the sound file.
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (
    soundFileURLRef,
    &soundFileObject
);
```

Play sound

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (soundFileObject);
```

Here is a nice tutorial [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) you can follow this